# how to replace a special characters by character using shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a string variable `x=tmp/variable/custom-sqr-sample/test/example` 
in the script, what I want to do is to replace all the “-” with the /, 
after that,I should get the following string

```
x=tmp/variable/custom/sqr/sample/test/example
```

Can anyone help me?

I tried the following syntax
it didnot work

```
exa=tmp/variable/custom-sqr-sample/test/example
exa=$(echo $exa|sed 's/-///g')
```

Comment: Try using different delimiters in your `sed` command.  I like pipes: `sed 's|-|/|g'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed basically supports any delimiter, which comes in handy when one tries to match a `/`, most common are `|`, `#` and `@`, pick one that's not in the string you need to work on.

```
$ echo $x
tmp/variable/custom-sqr-sample/test/example

$ sed 's#-#/#g' <<< $x
tmp/variable/custom/sqr/sample/test/example
```

In the commend you tried above, all you need is to escape the slash, i.e.

```
echo $exa | sed 's/-/\//g'
```

but choosing a different delimiter is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

The `tr` tool may be a better choice than `sed` in this case:

```
x=tmp/variable/custom-sqr-sample/test/example
echo "$x" | tr -- - /
```

(The `--` isn't strictly necessary, but keeps `tr` (and humans) from mistaking `-` for an option.)

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, you can use parameter substitution:

```sh
$ exa=tmp/variable/custom-sqr-sample/test/example
$ exa=${exa//-/\/}
$ echo $exa
tmp/variable/custom/sqr/sample/test/example
```